# Scope of #define preprocessor in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The scope of `#define` is till the end of the file. But where does it start from.
Basically I tried the following code.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #define pi 3.14
 void fun();
 int main()
{
 printf("%f \n",pi);
 #define pi 3.141516
    fun();
return 0;
}
void fun(){
printf("%f \n",pi);}
```

The output of the above program comes out to be

```
3.140000
3.141416
```

Considering preprocessing for main the value of pi should be 3.141516
and outside main 3.14. This is incorrect but please explain why.

Comment: Remember that it's PREprocessing.  It does not know or care about the structure of your code, in the case of #define it is doing substitutions in the order that it sees them relative to what the most recent value of the #defined variable is.

Comment: This code is actually ill-formed:  you cannot `#define` a macro with the same name as another macro that is currently defined unless their definitions are the same.  So, the second `#define pi` makes the program ill-formed.  You need to `#undef pi` first.

Comment: *The scope of #define is till the end of the file.* No, end of file **or #undef** of the same macro identifier.

Comment: BTW: Your value for pi is wrong.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2589.htm

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The C preprocessor runs through the file top-to-bottom and treats `#define` statements like a glorified copy-and-paste operation.  Once it encounters the line `#define pi 3.14`, it starts replacing every instance of the word `pi` with `3.14`.  The pre-processor does not process (or even notice) C-language scoping mechanisms like parenthesis and curly braces.  Once it sees a `#define`, that definition is in effect until either the end of the file is reached, the macro is un-defined with `#undef`, or (as in this case) the macro is re-defined with another `#define` statement.

If you are wanting constants that obey the C scoping rules, I suggest using something more on the lines of `const float pi = 3.14;`.

Comment: "or (as in this case) the macro is re-defined with another `#define` statement."  In fact, the second `#define` without a preceding `#undef` makes the program ill-formed.

Comment: Note that `const` does not create a constant usable, for instance, in switch labels: it creates a read-only object. Example at http://ideone.com/f3aON

Answer (score 11):

The scope of a `#define` is from the occurrence, to the end of the file (or a corresponding `#undef`), regardless of any intervening C scopes.

Comment: "*The scope of a `#define` is from the occurrence, to the end of the file*" - or if it is `#undef`'ed before EOF is reached.

Answer (score 4):

When you have preprocessor question:

> gcc -E foo.c > foo.i; vim foo.i

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor has no concept of "scope" -- it manipulates the text of the program, without any idea of what the text is

Symbol is defined from its definition until the end of the compilation unit (a source file and and files it includes)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what roughly looks like after the preprocessor done with your file:

```
 void fun();
 int main()
 {
    printf("%f \n",3.14);
   
    fun();
    return 0;
 }
 void fun(){
 printf("%f \n",3.141516);}
```

These are the lines that go to the compiler for compilation(I discarded many of the codes for the sake of clarity, only kept what you coded). As the preprocessor replaces the `#define` directive with the text/value you provided thus you don't see the `#define` directives anymore after preprocessing. So it is clear what is going to be printed on the console/terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the preprocessor uses `#define` statements in the order that it encounters them. In that case, your first `printf` statement correctly prints 3.14 and the second 3.141516 (is there a typo in the output from your program?).