# Is defines inside a class private to that class?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If I write something such as this:

```
class myclass
{
#define ADD(x,y) {return x+y}

public:

}
```

is the define private to my class?

note that I am defining it in *.hpp and I want to make sure that if I include this hpp to another source code, the other source code don't have access to this define.

Is there any better solution than using `#define` in C++ which can do the same thing?

What about using? is it private to my class or not?

```
class myclass
{
using std;

public:

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379489/scope-of-define-preprocessor-in-c

Comment: @DeathTails Thanks, that one if for C, and this is for c++, are they the same?

Comment: In this case, yes. The answer, and the reasons behind it, are exactly the same.

Comment: @PaulRoub Think we should dual tag that Q to use it as a dupe target for both languages?

Comment: No. And why would you want to use a preprocessor macro over a `const` or `constexpr` variable in the first place?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Can you elaborate your solution? How can I use const and constexpr instead of a #define in c++

Comment: Sorry, I meant function, not variable.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.  The question on using `using` should be its owns question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Seems justifiable.

Comment: Obviously didn't try it.

Answer (score 6):

It is not, and can never be.

All preprocessor commands (`#...`) are processed before the source code is ever read and analyzed, so it does not matter at all where you put them; only the sequence (if they build on each other) and the relative position to their usage (before/after) matters.

You can imagine preprocessor commands to be something like a 'find/replace from here on'.

Answer (score 0):

You may use #undef to limit the scope of a #define. Perhaps you could even use it to limit the scope of a define which you yourself did not create.